# How to get rid of Panel margins?

Tags: graphics, front-end

I have a feeling that there is something wrong in general with *Mathematica*'s way of dealing with margins and spaces among/around objects in `Graphics`, `Grid`-s, and alike. This is a constant problem for me, and for many others I assume. I usually end up to do some pixel-pushing or other workarounds, but this is getting more and more annoying with every year. Consider the following example:

```
 Panel[
     Graphics[{Circle[]},
        ImageSize -> 300, ImageMargins -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, 
        Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
        PlotRangePadding -> 0, Background -> White, 
        Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}],
     FrameMargins -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> All, 
     Background -> Lighter[Pink, .6]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have two questions related to the code above:

**Q1**: How to get rid of the pink frame margin without setting `Panel`'s `FrameMargins` explicitly to a negative number? I would assume, a zero-width margin is ... zero-width.

**Q2**: Why does the <strike>left</strike> right and bottom part of the `Frame` of the internal `Graphics` disappear and how can I prevent it?

**Edit**

Various workarounds can be used, e.g. `Pane` or `Framed`. The problem with these is that they don't have the look and feel `Panel` provides:

```
CreateDialog[Pane[{1, 2, 3}], WindowTitle -> "Pane"];
CreateDialog[Framed@Pane[{1, 2, 3}], WindowTitle -> "Framed Pane"];
CreateDialog[Panel[{1, 2, 3}], WindowTitle -> "Panel"];
```

While `Panel` looks good in a dialog window, the other two do not.

[image: Pane, Panel, Frame]

Comment: With styling options you can make both `Pane` and `Framed` look just like `Panel`; e.g. you can set `BaseStyle->"Panel"` and `FrameStyle->GrayLevel[.7]` etc to get the same looks. But I think the real advantage of `Panel` is its `Deployed` option which `Pane` and `Framed` does not support.

Comment: Oh good, I didn't know about `BaseStyle -> "Panel"`. I think the `Deployed` option can be substituted by a `Deploy` wrapper. Now I already suggested to @Szabolcs to make an answer out of his comment but I wish you two would couple up and write an answer combining both of your comments :)

Comment: You are right; any expression can be wrapped with `Deploy` to the same effect. I think @Szabolc's comment explains the puzzling behavior for us all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In these situations I like to use `Pane` instead of `Panel`.  It has no frame or extra margins.

```
Pane[Graphics[{Circle[]}, ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> None]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Does this help?

---

In case if you just want a `Panel` with no margins, not even the small margins that are left after `FrameMargins -> 0`:

The problem is that the `Panel` margin is styled by the operating system and will look different on different platforms. For example, on Windows XP it has an "engraved" look. This would be not possible without some extra margin. If we take away the system-styled margins, then all we're left with is a `Pane`.

Comment: Yes it helps, but it would be nice if I could do it with `Panel`. Does it mean that `Panel` is buggy?

Comment: @István It means that I misunderstood your question.  So you just want a `Panel` with no margins, not even the small margins that are left after `FrameMargins -> 0`, right?  The problem is that the `Panel` margin is styled by the operating system and will look different on different platforms.  For example, on Windows XP it has an "engraved" look.  This would be note possible without some extra margin.  If we take away the system-styled margins, then all we're left with is a `Pane`.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm sure you are right about OS depending behaviour of Panel, but is this written somewhere? Or further, how to check which objects` looks depend of OS? Sure, Sliders etc but this is an observation, not a documented fact.

Comment: @Kuba I just assumed that if a control looks like a standard GUI control that I also see in other programs, then it must be rendered by the OS, so it must be OS-dependent.  Perhaps this is not so obvious for `Panel`s on Windows because of the very plain appearance.  On OS X they're [quite heavily styled](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0laiicaqzd7s3d3/Screenshot%202014-02-19%2011.56.55.png).  BTW it's possible to use a generic, platform independent appearance with `Style[..., ControlsRendering -> "Generic"]`.  This rendering is also used when exporting to PDF/EPS.

Answer (score 5):

`Framed` is a way to avoid the frustrations with `Panel`; that is, `...Margins` settings work as one would expect: With `FrameMargins->0` and `FrameMargins->1` the following

```
 Row[{Framed[
 Graphics[{Circle[]}, ImageSize -> 300, ImageMargins -> 0, 
 ImagePadding -> 4, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> .4, 
 Background -> White, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}], 
 FrameMargins -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> All, 
 Background -> Lighter[Pink, .6]], "   ", 
Framed[Graphics[{Circle[]}, ImageSize -> 300, ImageMargins -> 0, 
ImagePadding -> 4, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, 
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> .4, 
Background -> White, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}], 
FrameMargins -> 1, ImageMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> All, 
Background -> Lighter[Pink, .6]]}]
```

gives

[image: framed with FrameMargins 0 and 1]

Comment: Thanks kguler, this is working fine, but does not solve all my problems. See edit in my post.

Comment: @Istvan, possibly a cut/paste error in your second example:  `Framed@Pane` versus just `Framed`.

Comment: It does not matter, the dialog output will look like the same.

Answer (score 4):

With respect to your second question,

> Q2: Why does the left and bottom part of the Frame of the internal Graphics disappear and how can I prevent it?

Did you mean to say "right and bottom part of the Frame..."?

In any case, you might want to experiment with `PlotRangePadding`. For, example, PlotRangePadding -> 0.01 produces the following:

[image: PlotRangePadding1]

You can also adjust the `PlotRangePadding` on the {{left, right}, {bottom,top}}, as in 
`PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0.01}, {0.01, 0}}` (see below):

[image: PlotRangePadding2]

or `PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0.01}, {0.03, 0}}`

I don't understand why adding the additional padding to the bottom causes the black line to appear. I had thought the black lines at the left and top were to convey shadows (to create the illusion that the panel were slightly sunken), but a bottom shadow works against this interpretation.

[image: PlotRangePadding3]

I don't think this solves your problem but it may shed some light on it.