# Symmetric FrameMargins problem

Tags: output-formatting, gui-construction

Such details are driving me crazy while creating GUIs with *Mathematica*:

```
Panel[
  Panel["", Background -> Yellow, ImageMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> {26, 26}]
  , Background -> Black, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

Margins above are symmetric in vertical and horizontal direction, let's say I want to take control and specify `FrameMargins`:

```
Panel[
  Panel["", Background -> Yellow, ImageMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> {26, 26}]
  , Background -> Black, Alignment -> Center, FrameMargins -> {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Now clearly they are not. I used `1` because then it is easily seen but the value does not matter.

Am I missing something?

**Edit**

With `Framed` it seems to be ok, but one have to add `FrameStyle->None`.

Comment: On OS X, v 9.0.0.0 both examples are symmetric. Perhaps  it is a bug with OS/MMA version that you're using.

Comment: @Anon Probably, now I'm on winXP with MMA 9.0.1.0.

Comment: it works ok on windows 7, V 9.01, screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rpJVI.png)

Comment: If you are using `Panel` with custom bg, it can be approximated with `Graphics`. Would this solve the problem? `Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {26, 26}], Yellow, Rectangle[{0, 0} + 3, {26, 26} - 3]}, ImageSize -> 26, ImageMargins -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0]` ([related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1247/89))

Comment: @IstvánZachar Only partially, now I have to care about image size when with `Panel` I didn't have to.

Comment: I can reproduce this on Windows 2003. Very strange for this to be OS version-dependent. Same result in versions 8.0.4 and 7.0.1, albeit the asymmetry is less pronounced in the latter (the top margin is slightly thicker).

Comment: I saw no problem with the `FrameMargins` version, when I evaluated it in V.9.0.1 on OS X 10.6.8

Comment: On Windows 7 x64 in MMa 8.0.4 both examples are symmetric.