# Panel size undesired behaviour

Tags: functions, output-formatting, grid-layouts, gui-construction

This is  next question from the series: *better avoid* `Panel` *if you care about details.* [previous about `FrameMargins`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40326/5478)

In the following example `ImageSize` is on purpose not big enough to display `1`, we will see that this causes the `Panel` to fool us about it's `ImageSize`.

First case:

```
With[{opt = Sequence[ImageSize -> {20, 20}, ImageMargins -> 0, Background -> Orange]},
 Row[{
   Panel[1, opt],
   Panel[1, opt]
   }]]
```

> [image]

```
With[{opt = Sequence[ImageSize -> {20, 20}, ImageMargins -> 0, Background -> Orange]},
     Row[{
       Panel[1, opt],
       Panel[1, opt, FrameMargins -> 0]
       }]]
```

> [image]

Again, there is no problem with `Framed`.

WinXP V9.0.1

Is this OS dependent problem too? Is [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs) appriopriate tag?, because I see no reason that `FrameMargins` should affect overall `ImageSize`.

Comment: Are you complaining about the two panels in the 2nd example not being the same size? They are for me running V9.0.1 on OS X.

Comment: @m_goldberg Yes. Well, I was expecting it is OS dependent, like the linked one. Now I'm waiting for WRI answer.

Comment: Any reply from WRI?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard this is what they sent: 2) The second issue appears to affect only smaller ImageSize of 10 or 20 px.
I checked with a developer about this issue and this is what he has to say. 
------------------------------------
On comparing these two:
 Panel[1, ImageSize -> {10, 10}]
 Panel[1, ImageSize -> {20, 20}]
 vs.
 Panel[1, ImageSize -> {10, 10}, FrameMargins -> 0]
 Panel[1, ImageSize -> {20, 20}, FrameMargins -> 0]
  tbc...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ... " Without explicit FrameMargins, Panel changes very little at these 
 sizes. But, with FrameMargins -> 0, it does. I suspect setting 
 FrameMargins -> 0 removes a constraint on the minimum size that is 
 imposed by the default FrameMargins setting. So, at theses sizes, I 
 don't think it is a bug, just it initially seems odd."